# How to compare two unions for ordering

Tags: c++, dictionary, unions

I have a class that's to act as a `map` key, which contains two members

```
struct Key{
    unsigned int type;
    union{
        Enumerator thing1;
        int32 thing2;
        struct{int16 a; bool b;} thing3;
        ... etc...
    }data;

    bool operator<(const Key & rh) const{
        if(type == rh.type){
            ???
        }else{
            return type < rh.type;
        }
    }
}
```

The second member `data` is a union, and I'm unsure how to compare it against another of it's type in a way that's agnostic of what union member was last assigned (a switch in the lessthan operator would be too costly)

It's not important the ordering, all that matters is that different values are seen as different by the map.  Is there a way to do a fast bit compare on two unions?

Comment: if your condition `if(type == rh.type)` you have to write a switch on the 3 possible types, and for each type compare either thing1, either thing2, either thing3.

Comment: How do you know that "a switch in the lessthan operator would be too costly"? Have you measured?

Comment: @Pierre - the actual Key contains about 16 different union members, many of which are technically the same type underneath, so it'd be a very large switch statement

Comment: You can group them in the switch by doing `case TYPE1: case TYPE2: case TYPE3:  /* comparison */break; case TYPE3: /* comparison */ break;`. There wont be any common comparison function with types like `struct { int; bool }`, you have to write explicitly the meaning of `<` on that kind of struct

Comment: @AnneQuinn: "it'd be a very large switch statement". It'll be a fair few lines of code, but it's not difficult to do. So write it and test its performance. Unless by "costly" you mean that longer code takes more dev time to maintain ;-)

Comment: @ecatmur - yes, it showed up as being the hottest path in my event handler; the underlying map can reorder multiple times a frame, which in turn calls the operator frequently.  Any optimization here is likely to have a big impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there can't be a single type-agnostic bytewise comparison. `thing2` and `thing3` have different numbers of bytes participating in their values (that is, different amounts of padding), so you can't use `std::memcmp` or any other comparison of the raw memory.

If the types run consecutively from 0 (or anyway, are reasonably small numbers), then you could perhaps look up a size to compare from an array indexed by `type`, *provided* that all the padding in all the union members is at the end, such that all bytes participating in the value are at the start. `thing3` already might fail this test, if `bool` is bigger than `int16`, and we don't know what's in `Enumerator` and `... etc ...`

In theory you could avoid a switch using an array of function pointers, indexed by `type`. But there's no particular reason to expect that to be any faster than a switch once the optimizer has done its work. Generally speaking, function pointers are death to inlining and so they cripple the optimizer and the CPU's own speculative instruction fetching/execution.

By the way, if you don't care about the order then `std::unordered_map` will generally perform better than `std::map`, but you'll still have this issue of needing to write a hash function that only hashes the bytes that participate in the value.

Comment: function pointers would be a necessity if the functionnality has to be modular, and it will help a lot to avoid code repetition. If it's just one class, there is no need for function pointers.

Comment: @Pierre: sure, I'm just considering one of the obvious "workarounds" the questioner might consider since she's (unnecessarily IMO) concerned by large switches. It has the significant disadvantage of almost certainly being slower, but if there's plenty of developer time available to spend on this problem then it might be worth a quick test to be certain.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way, but now that I know there isn't, I can rework the design to do away with the union.  Also thank you for the tip on `unordered_map`, I'll use that then

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires modification to `union` as well as the places condition on values which can be taken by the members of `union`. Please Note: This might not be the required answer but a possible way to compare that's agnostic of what union member was last assigned.

Make every member of `union` of same size. Since anyways, max size of member will be considered so it doesn't matter having same size.
Now decide the domain of values for the members.
Let's say:

- domain of thing1 is {A,B,C....}
- domain of thing2 is {P,Q,R....}
- domain of thing3 is {X,Y,Z....}

Now if you can ensure A,P,X are of logically equal weight/priority/value w.r.t comparison then 2 instances of `union` `this->data` and `rh.data` can be compared using normal relational operators in same way as you have compared `this->type` and `rh.type` 
Similarly, B,Q,Y should be of logically equal weight/priority/value w.r.t comparison. Same applies to other corresponding values of things1, thing2 and thing3.